# Trying to edit a row of a csv file in python, but for some reason it also adds blank rows when run?

Tags: python, list, csv

I'm trying to make it so you can edit a single client's details in a csv file, and while the code I wrote runs it for some reason adds a gap in between each client as well as changing the client - i'd really appreciate if someone could tell me why this is happening.

Here's an excerpt of my csv:

```
first_name,last_name,title,pronouns,dob,occupation,account_balance,overdraft_limit
Genovera,Willgoss,Mrs,Female,25/05/2022,Graphic Designer,2315.16,46.48
Garner,Coupman,Ms,Male,14/04/2022,General Manager,2200.76,2.28
Jens,Eldrid,Honorable,Male,13/11/2021,Research Associate,967.64,79.15
```

The code i'm running:

```
if choice == "4":
    editClient = int(input("Please enter the index number of the client you wish to edit:"))
    print("Please enter the details for each of the following:")
    for i in range(len(existing_clients[0])):
        newDetails = input("Enter new data for " + str(existing_clients[0][i]) + ":")
        existing_clients[editClient][i] = newDetails
    changes = input("Are you sure you'd like to make these changes? Enter Yes or No")
    if changes == ("Yes"):
        with open("mock_data.csv", "w+") as file:
            reader = csv.writer(file)
            for i in range(len(existing_clients)):
                reader.writerow(existing_clients[i])
```

And what my csv looks like after i've changed a client:
(I just changed all of Jens details to 1)

```
first_name,last_name,title,pronouns,dob,occupation,account_balance,overdraft_limit

Genovera,Willgoss,Mrs,Female,25/05/2022,Graphic Designer,2315.16,46.48

Garner,Coupman,Ms,Male,14/04/2022,General Manager,2200.76,2.28

1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
```

I haven't tried anything because i've got no idea whats making this happen - I've only been programming a month and am very lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it is adding an extra carriage return when writing.  Try changing this line:

`with open("mock_data.csv", "w+") as file:`

to

`with open("mock_data.csv", newline= "", "w+") as file:`

Comment: @Nikki awesome, if you could accept it as an answer (the little check mark) that would help out :)